# Any other machine learning library in Hadoop platform except mahout

Tags: hadoop, machine-learning

I am working on a project which leverage machine learning algorithm, and i select hadoop/mahout because it can handle big data better.

but mahout only integrated few algorithms,(does not include some algorithm, like SVM) so i want to know is there any other machine learning library in Hadoop platform except mahout

if so, i have some question about new library

1. does it support distributed computing
2. is it official release? any support?

Thanks a lot~

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at `Apache Hama`, they feature simple ML algorithms like `Logistic Regression` or `K-means` clustering. There will be more algorithms in the future.

Here is their site:

http://hama.apache.org/

Answer (score -1):

basically  you can use Weka or many other tools on hadoop. Just keep in mind that you will benefit from hadoop + ML algorithm only if the ML algorithm is based on map-reduce technique. Otherwise there won't be any improvement. I'm not sure, but I strongly doubt that SVM is based on map-reduce ...